# How to make sense of Law of energy conservation in the case of two Inductors carrying different currents switched in series together all of a sudden

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, energy-conservation, inductance

Here is the first circuit,

[image]

The circuit is in steady state, the current though $3H$ inductor is $3A$ and $6H$ inductor is $6A$. The flux produced are $9WbT$ and $36WbT$, total $45WbT$. If I calculate the energy stored in the inductors, I get the values $13.5J$ and $108J$ respectively, total of $121.5J$

Now the switches are brought to the flipped state as shown,

[image]

Which is same as,

[image]

To find the current in steady state, I used Laplace transform method to redraw the circuit including the initial states of the inductors as,

[image]

Applying Kirchhoff's rule here, I find that the current in the circuit is $5A$. Therefore the fluxes in this scenario are $15WbT$ and $30WbT$, total $45Wbt$, flux is conserved. But the energy stored in the inductors are $37.5J$ and $75J$, together, $112.5J$, not $121.5J$ as in earlier. There is a difference of $-9J$

This is where I'm lost, There is no resistance in the circuit to dissipate energy, where did the rest of the energy go? The total flux is indeed constant.

Comment: How did you arrive at the initial state for the inductors (post-switch)? Inductors will generate voltage to prevent current through them changing. I would therefore expect that as you would try to disconnect the switches there will be a spark jumping between your connectors. This also points that disconnection of the circuit may not be trivial in these energy balance questions. Will you need energy to break this connection, or will there be energy released? You have 6A going through one inductor and 3A through another. What will happen with the excessive charge when you switch?

Comment: The inductors has currents flowing in then and t tend to zero minus. Coupling that with Laplace transform equivalent of the inductor I get the initial state of inductor. As to your other questions, I don't know that's why I asked this question. This is a hypothetical scenario, are you saying even thinking about this scenario is pointless?

Comment: Re, "There is no resistance in the circuit to dissipate energy." This is a fundamental problem when drawing idealized circuit diagrams. Real circuits behave differently from ideal circuits. For a lot of practical designs, the difference is small enough to ignore, but in extreme cases (especially, _transients_) you can't ignore it. Real wires, real coils have resistance. Sometimes, you have to add phantom components to the diagram (e.g., a resistor symbol labelled, $R_\text{internal}$) in order to bring its prediction closer to the real behavior.

Comment: Of course, you could build that entire circuit out of superconducting wire and immerse the whole thing in liquid helium. I don't know what happens then, but consider that there's also phantom capacitance, and there's also the fact that changes only propagate at finite speed... Maybe set up an oscillation, in which case, energy will be radiated away as electromagnetic waves.

Comment: I'm not talking about a real circuit, this is a hypothetical scenario. I'm completely aware real inductors have resistances. The answer below says that the difference in energy was probably radiated as electromagnetic waves.

Comment: I understand. But I'm saying that sometimes, the hypothetical scenarios, that are easy to draw on paper, don't follow your intuition. A big clue is when you apply the laws, do the math, and you get infinities. That's a sign that the model you have constructed is unphysical.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to apply Kirchhoff's laws, which also give rise to application of Laplace transform too simplistically. Kirchhoff's laws are approximations of Maxwell's equations in the limit of electro-/magneto-statics (and few other things).

Here you propose to break the connection in the circuit. There are several ways of doing it.

Do it slow, like raising the resistance, and Kirchhoff's laws will apply but nothing interesting will happen. The inductors will simply discharge energy into resistance.

Do it fast, and you will have electromagnetic waves running along wires as charges will attempt to find new equilibrium position. You may get arcing, you may get radio-wave emission, you may get heating, and many other things. Precisely what you will get will depend on how you do the disconnection. Moreover, the final state will depend on how you did the disconnection.

So you cannot, I am afraid, simply say, "We break the connection". This is insufficient information to describe what the system will do. What I am certain of is that if you disconnect fast, Kirchhoff's laws won't suffice. You will need to do full Maxwell's equation solving, perhaps with additional coupling of heat transfer in wires. Maybe even with some modelling of arcing in air.

Also note, that energy conservation will break in both scenarios. In slow scenario, extra resistance will eat energy. In fast scenario, your energy will go into heating and radio-wave emission.

Comment: So if there is no resistance the energy difference I calculated is probably dissipated as EM radiation and arcing.

Comment: Who said there is no resistance? I don't think you can just assume it. You have not provided enough information on how you would break the contact. One extreme scenario I had in my mind is have contact wires vaporized by ultra-fast laser. That could possibly happen fast enough. What you will have in that case, assuming arcing will not follow, is that some of the energy will be dissipated into radiation.

Comment: I said, in the question itself. This is a hypothetical scenario, so breaking the connection is also done very fast, for example like you said by high speed lasers, or hypothetically, ideal mechanical switches breaking connection at a speed close to light speed.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that your second circuit is impossible. Switching inductors is generally problematic anyway. An ideal switch will keep the current in each inductor the same before and after. Here, if you do that you will have two inductors with different initial currents in series. That is impossible. Something will necessarily break in this circuit. Most likely is that when switching there will be a rather large spark. That spark will briefly act as a very large resistance across which a lot of energy will be rapidly dissipated.

Comment: Ok, but are my calculations theoretically correct? I mean In the same way I can analyze  the case two different capacitors holding different voltages are connected in parallel.

Comment: @ASWIN VENU. Difference with capacitors is that there is no current flowing, so you can gradually break the connection without ever leaving the electrostatic regime.

Comment: @ASWINVENU No, even theoretically you cannot have two different currents in series nor can you theoretically have two different voltages in parallel. Both lead to inconsistent equations with no solution

Comment: I mean this was a question asked for the entrance exam for masters in Electrical engineering at national universities in India. I'm not saying about different currents flowing in a series connection, I'm asking if I am right to have calculated that a five amperes of current will flow in the circuit at steady state.

Comment: @ASWINVENU no matter who asks the question it is impossible to answer. It is a self-contradiction. You cannot have two different currents in series. Probably the question was intended for you to recognize the impossibility